# Extract specific backupfiles from SQL Server 2008 backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a big .bak file containing a full backup and some transaction log backups. Is it possible to extract only the transaction log backups so I can copy them to another PC? (the full backup has already been restored and I don't want to send the big *.bak file again)

Answer (score 2):

Not with the native tools.  Thinking about it, I can see how somebody could write a tool to do it, but there's nothing off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have an answer. 
But if I were you and I don't find any tool to extract specific backup then I would just create new backup which is not in existing backup group and use it where ever I am needed to use it. (since you already have fully restored backup you can use it to create antoehr backup.)